# Gradient annotator is not appearing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

[image][image]gradient annotator is not appearing suddenly. any suggestions?

what I had done so far-

reinstalled illustrator. (am using illustrator 2020)
, restarted PC.

but nothing changes. activating gradient if I move my mouse A no-access sign with a doted plus appears each time. :(  please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the **stroke** highlighted in the **Gradient Panel**.

[image]

The Gradient Annotator does **not** work or appear for gradients on *strokes*. 
The annotator will **only** appear for **fills**.

Comment: OH MY GOD! it came back! Thank you so much! wasted hours on this...

Comment: yes, I have outlined all those strokes now the gradient bar is appearing. I didn't know this. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, would you please see this?? I have attached another picture. but my gradient bar is not appearing here. I have selected the fill and outlined all stroked, but still, the bar is not showing. what is happening now?

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin The annotator doesn't appear on **compound shapes** either. (Shapes with "holes" in them.) You don't **need** the annotator. All adjustments can be made in the Gradient Panel.

Comment: Thank you @scott. oh god... so many things yet to learn...  :'(