# Can't edit gradient applied to a stroke in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, stroke

I'm trying to change the direction of a gradient that I applied to the outside of 3 grouped objects but illustrator is not giving me the option to edit gradient
Any solution to this, please???[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. In your first screenshot, it looks like you haven't selected the object to which the stroke is actually applied. You seem to have selected the group. Without knowing exactly how this has been constructed, not sure how much help I can give. Maybe start by ungrouping, and then try to find the right object - I suspect a text object. Then you should be able to edit the gradient as normal.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering!!
If I ungroup it, the stroke won't be added to all of them together. 
And there's no way to select just the outer stroke

Comment: It depends how this has been constructed. There could for example be a group of the letter shapes which has a stroke effect applied, and then another group of everything including the highlights.  You can have groups within groups. It's hard to tell without knowing how this has been constructed. You will likely need to deconstruct it, or work it out yourself.

Comment: Also have a look at your layers panel, objects with an effect in the appearance panel have a little [grey filled circle](https://imgur.com/2VQs5EF)

Comment: From your screenshots would appear that you **do** have options to adjust the gradient. How *specifically* are you trying to edit the gradient? Or what *specifically* are you expecting to see which you aren't? -- For example.. the gradient annotator - that bar that appears over objects when fills have gradients, that does **not** appear for strokes. If you are expecting to see the annotator, you *never* will for a stroke with a gradient.

Comment: In that case, this would be a duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137931/gradient-annotator-is-not-appearing

Comment: Thanks 
I am trying to see the slider so I can change the direction of the gradient, I want the dark blue to be on top and light on the bottom. If it doesn't work, do you have any suggestion on how I could achieve that/]?

Comment: I searched it up and didn't find that post before, sorry. I was able to figure out a way to do it. I expanded the appearance, ungrouped them all and made the stroke it's own object in the background using the shape builder tool. Thank you for all the replies

Comment: It's never possible to change direction fo gradients on strokes - other than reverse the gradient. There are the 3 options on the Gradient panel - within, along, and across - those are all one can do for *strokes*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradient annotator is not appearing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137931/gradient-annotator-is-not-appearing)